# Installing openSUSE 15.4 as a PV Xen Guest (DomU) on Debian 11 - cannot find kernel to link in xen-tools configuration

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, opensuse, xen

we are currently trying to set up a virtualized environment in which we would like to use openSUSE 15.4 Leap as a Xen Guest (DomU) on a Debian 11 Host.

To do so I have found some resources which adress the matter, but may be a little bit dated:

- [How to install a openSuSE domU on a Debian dom0](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/How_to_install_a_openSuSE_domU_on_a_Debian_dom0)
- [Building an RPM based (Red Hat, Fedora, CentOS) Xen Guest Root Filesystem using Rinse](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Building_an_RPM_based_(Red_Hat,_Fedora,_CentOS)_Xen_Guest_Root_Filesystem_using_Rinse)

My configuration file looks like this currently:

```
#
# Configuration file for the Xen instance test2, created manually
# 
#
#
#  Kernel + memory size
#
kernel      = '/opensuse-15.4/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.21-150400.24.33-default'
ramdisk     = '/bootfiles/initrd'
vcpus       = '4'
memory      = '16384'
#
#  Disk device(s).
#
root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'
disk        = [
                  'file:/home/xen/domains/testsuserpm/disk.img,xvda2,w',
                  'file:/home/xen/domains/testsuserpm/swap.img,xvda1,w',
              ]
#
#  Hostname
#
name        = 'testsuserpm'
#
#  Networking
#
dhcp        = 'dhcp'
vif         = [ 'mac=,bridge=xenbr0' ]
#
#  Behaviour
#
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
```

I got the kernel file by converting the .rpm package into a .deb package and installing the file into some folder to perform a [Direct Kernel Boot](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Booting_Overview). As for the installation I used rinse based on the following [HowTo](https://fai-project.org/doc/karsten/rinse%20verwenden.pdf) and put it onto the disk image that is linked within the config file. However upon trying to start the vm I get the following error message:

> Parsing config from /etc/xen/testsuserpm.cfg ': lexical
> errorerpm.cfg:8: config parsing error near `': lexical errorerpm.cfg:9: config parsing error near` ': lexical
> errorerpm.cfg:10: config parsing error near `': lexical errorerpm.cfg:11: config parsing error near` ': lexical
> errorerpm.cfg:15: config parsing error near `': lexical errorerpm.cfg:16: config parsing error near` ': lexical
> errorerpm.cfg:17: config parsing error near `': lexical errorerpm.cfg:18: config parsing error near` ': lexical
> errorerpm.cfg:19: config parsing error near `': lexical errorerpm.cfg:23: config parsing error near` ': lexical
> errorerpm.cfg:27: config parsing error near `': lexical errorerpm.cfg:28: config parsing error near` ': lexical
> errorerpm.cfg:32: config parsing error near `': lexical errorerpm.cfg:33: config parsing error near` Failed to parse config:
> Invalid argument

I am guessing installing a .rpm based package on Debian just like that is not possible. Is there anything I could do to make this work?

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be less hassle in the long run to start a PV domU via a host-provided grub2 binary. Most likely Debian already provides such thing. If not, it is part of all SUSE releases in the `grub2-x86_64-xen.rpm` package as `/usr/share/grub2/x86_64-xen/grub.xen`.

Put this binary into the `kernel=` line, if also the install iso image is provided as a disk.

Otherwise copy `boot/x86_64/loader/linux` and `boot/x86_64/loader/initrd` from the install media to the host, and put both into `kernel=` and `ramdisk=`. This will start the installer. It will in turn look for an installation media. It may default to `https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.4/repo/oss/`, if not boot the installer with this in the kernel cmdline `install=https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.4/repo/oss/`

The used `root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'` is not needed, should be removed. The used initrd will already know where its root filesystem is, based on the UUID.